# Anti-adhesive agent for soot particles in the exhuast gas

Tags: organic-chemistry

I would like to know if there is/are any anti-adhesive agent for the soot particles (soot particles can be considered as the group of carbon particles) i.e., the agent which will prevent two carbon particles sticking togther and leading to agglomeration.

Thank you.